# Error while installing Sitecore 10.2 xp0 in docker while running docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up Sitecore 10.2 xp0 in docker but I am getting error when I run the command `docker-compose up -d`
Below is the error I get-

Please let me know how can this be fixed.

```
Step 7/11 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"
 ---> Running in 4a20f6fbca6c
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish
trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... yContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandl ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

- Downloaded `nuget.exe`, manually using this https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.6.0/nuget.exe
- Create an empty folder as `Nuget` under `C:\Program Files`. ex. `-- C:\Program Files\Nuget`
- Copy the `nuget.exe` to `C:\Program Files\Nuget\`
- Comment this line in Dockerfile, available in `ROOT_PROJECT\docker\build\dotnetsdk\Dockerfile`

  ```
  ## RUN `Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.6.0/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"`
  ```
- Afterwards run `.\up.ps1` again

Hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I still have some issue but your solution solved that specific problem so I marked it as answer.